# remove text from the page which is under no tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have html page which is appearing properly but it has some dynamic text which is coming, and it is under no tag. how can i remove that text using jquery.

The text is coming as:

```
<div id="Container2" class="tab default-tab" style="display: block; margin-top: -15px; overflow: auto; width: 990px; height: 400px;">   
<!-- start -->

Search Setup 1 FIA - need to remove this {the text appearing is dynamic}

<style>other contents go here
```

Comment: Why is the text there in the first place? Surely you want to stop the text getting there rather then removing it.

Comment: All text in the page is "under a tag," even if it's only the `<body>` tag. Also, as haxtbh notes, treating the symptoms (removing the text) is not curing the disease (that the text is appearing at all).

Comment: There isn't **no tag**, an `html` is always there. Make your requirement more accurate.

Comment: where did your `div` closed? show all your codes or try to create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This code find raw text in div and remove it

```js
$("#Container2").contents().each(function(index, elem) {
  if ($.trim(elem.nodeValue) != '' && elem.nodeType == 3){
    alert($.trim(elem.nodeValue))
    $(elem).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container2" class="tab default-tab" style="display: block; margin-top: -15px; overflow: auto; width: 990px; height: 400px;">   
<!-- start -->
Search Setup 1 FIA - need to remove this {the text appearing is dynamic}
<span>other contents go here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html is morel ike

```
<div id="Container2" class="tab default-tab">   
<!-- start -->

Search Setup 1 FIA - need to remove this {the text appearing is dynamic}

<span>other contant here</span>
 </div>
```

And you only want to get rid of the *text* content of the div, but not the span within it, you can do it like this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#Container2').contents()
                  .filter(function(){
                       return this.nodeType == 3; // text nodes
                  })
                  .remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container2" class="tab default-tab">   
<!-- start -->

Search Setup 1 FIA - need to remove this {the text appearing is dynamic}

<span>other contant here</span>
 </div>
```